# Detecting middle button mouseup outside the window on Chrome / Mac OS

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

Binding the `mouseup` event to the `window` object usually triggers even if the mouse button was released outside the window (as long as it was pressed down inside the window). This is very helpful to get drag and drop (and similar) to cancel even though the mouse left the window.

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => console.log("mouseup"));
```

But I’m having an issue where it does not trigger with the **middle mouse button** on **Chrome** (91) on **Mac OS** (Catalina).

Note that it works fine with the left mouse button, it works fine in Safari on the same computer (with the middle mouse button), and it works fine on Chrome on Windows.

Is this a bug in Chrome for Mac? Is there a workaround? I’m making an app where I need to pan using the middle mouse button, so I want to cancel it even if we release the button outside the window.

Comment: It works, in case of macOs High Sierra + Chrome Version 91. Do you check the same code with Safari and Chrome? Will it work in Chrome with imitation of middle mouse click with MouseEvent?

Comment: Hmm, yes I checked the same code with both Safari and Chrome (the line in the code block above, on codepen.io). I’m not sure how to imitate a mouse click outside the window.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to make a mouse click inside the window and release outside. From my point of view, setTimeout should make a trick.

Comment: I want to detect when the middle mouse button gets released, whether or not it is inside the window, just like it’s possible for the left mouse button, or on Safari, or on Chrome/Windows. I don’t see how setTimeout would help. I would also like to get mousemove events outside the window, they get blocked as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that someone already reported it on the Chromium bug tracker two months ago, so it does seem to be a Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1206068

In order to work around it, I’m now simply checking `e.buttons` on the `mousemove` event, in order to cancel the dragging if the mouse comes back to the window without any button pressed. Not perfect but better than nothing.